# how to read and parse html file without writing on disc

Tags: python

Recently I wrote a python script to parse a specific line from a webpage. This code is working fine but whenever I run it, it downloads and writes a file ".php" on working directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wget
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import tempfile
url = "http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/quicksearch.php?gene+name=0009&submit=Search#sequence"
filname = wget.download(url)
a = open(filname,'r')
b = a.readlines()
f = "|Rv0009|"
for c in b:
    if f in c:
        pattern = re.compile("> >.+<br /></")
        z = pattern.findall(c)
        print z
```

What changes should I make so that without writing a file it would parse the desired line.

Comment: You could use the `urllib2` module (or the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module, if you have it) to download the page's contents into a variable in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

- `urllib.urlopen(url)` will give you a file-like object and not write anything on the disk.
- Your code is importing 2 modules (`HTMLParser` and `tempfile`) that it's not using. Get rid of those imports.
- The `#sequence` part of your URL is never given to the server (it's part of the HTTP spec). You can take it out.
- You're using regular expressions to parse HTML. As your use case complexifies, it will lead you to pain and suffering. Consider using lxml.html (http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) or BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.